# Oil light comes on and off when oil life is 90%

Tags: engine, oil-change, scheduled-maintenance, oil-level, oil-life-indicator

I have a Honda Civic 2013. I recently had the oil & filter change. Everything was fine for a week until recently the car has started giving irregular "check engine oil" lights. The light comes on just for a second or two when I am driving and goes off immediately. My maintenance panel tells me the engine oil is at 90%. So I am not really sure what is happening here. Is it something serious that I have to get fixed asap and avoid driving?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it warning you for the level and not life? Have you checked? Might be a **very** good idea... otherwise you might get an expensive bang...

Comment: So I just checked again. I guess its a different issue but still nit sure how to approach it. When I drive, the warning that comes on is "Check engine oil level" and my car manual says that this warning is for Low oil pressure indicator. Is it something to worry about? And can I drive my car to mechanic?

Comment: Have you checked the engine oil level in the sump with the dipstck? I am not sure how I can make it much clearer...

Comment: I will give you an update on the oil levels soon as I just reached at work now.

Comment: So I checked the oil level and it is less than a quart. I think there is some sort of leakage of oil because otherwise, it can not happen as I just had the oil & filter change two weeks ago. Seems like they did something terribly wrong. Do you recommend driving it to the nearest mechanic?

Comment: Most likely cause of that is that they didn't fully fill with oil when they did the oil change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the oil light automatically turns off, and it's red not yellow, it is the oil pressure light!

It means "stop driving now! imminent engine damage possible!"

Do check the oil level. If it's ok, you may be lucky and it's possible the oil pressure sensor has some issues. Or, it may be the case that the engine really has sometimes too low oil pressure.

I wouldn't drive on a car with flickering red engine oil light without at least having the lubrication system checked by a competent mechanic... The damage could be very expensive.

Comment: the word "imminent" means - not possible to avoid, so it's beyond "possible"... :)